# circle progress bar animation speed issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

I am using this code for a circle progress bar with play and stop button, when I click the play button then the progress bar starts animate, and when I click the stop button its animation stop and this is working fine. Basically I notice that the progress bar animation speed is not same throughout the cycle, In the start, animation move slowly and gradually animation speed is increased step by step, so I want to make and manage the animation speed same and equal throughout the cycle from a start point to the endpoint, can you please explain how I can achieve this functionality.

```js
var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(containercheck, {
    color: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 8,
    trailWidth: 9,
    strokeColor: 'red',
    easing: 'easeInOut',
    duration: 30000,
    text: {
        autoStyleContainer: true
    },
    from: {
        color: '#3f81bd',
        width: 8
    },
    to: {
        color: '#3f81bd',
        width: 8
    },
    // Set default step function for all animate calls
    step: function(state, circle) {
        circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
        circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);
        var value = Math.round(circle.value() * 30);
        if (value === 0) {
            circle.setText('<span class="numberValue">' + 0 + '</span>' +
                '<span>Exercise</span>');
        } else {
            circle.setText('<span class="numberValue">' + value + '</span>' +
                '<span>Exercise</span>');
        }
    }
});
bar.text.style.fontFamily = '"Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif';
bar.text.style.fontSize = '20px';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation-timing function should be linear instead of `ease-in-out`
add  this to your code: `animation-timing-function: linear;`  i.e. `easing: 'linear'`

Comment: actually, when I stop the animation and then hit to play again, in this case, progress bar animation start slowly and takes more than time to reach the endpoint.

Comment: cause you did  `ease-in-out`